# Notification Hubs - Registering Existing Userbase

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-notificationhub

We are currently have our own implementation of push notifications on our server has the push notification ID's of ~2 million users. However, our system has some issues with this scale so we are considering Notification Hubs as an alternative.

We've already integrated the relevant server code necessary to register each user on login, but in order to reach all users who might not have logged in recently, we need to register all our users manually once. I've created a simple console app that does this by looping through our database, creating relevant tags and registering them with the hub.

However, running this against a test database with only 300,000 users, the program is extremely slow. It only registers a 1000 users every 1.25 minutes, meaning the whole 300,000 could take upwards of 6 hours and 2 millions could take days.

Here is a small sample of what the console app looks like:

```
var accounts = GetUsers();
Parallel.Foreach(accounts, account =>
{
      var registration = Register(user.ID, user.pushID).Result;
});

async Task<RegistrationDescription> Register(int ID, string pushID)
{
    string ID = "ID-" + ID;
    HashSet<string> tags = new HashSet<string>();
    tags.Add(ID);

    return await client.CreateAppleNativeRegistrationAsync(pushID, tags);      
}
```

---

**Q: Is there a convenient way to quickly register a large existing user base with Notification Hubs?**

---

Comment: I don't know of another way to do the registrations external to the client. Out of curiosity, when you ran your test did you do it within Visual Studio with the debugger attached?  On one occasion in the past I've seen a big difference in a app that makes HTTP requests like this when it is ran from VS and when the executable is ran directly.

Comment: I've tried both with and without the debugger. The time it takes is about is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is no, there's not a built-in feature of Notification Hubs to support mass registrations. However, it doesn't have to be a giant hurdle to make this go more quickly.

From where are you executing this code? If you are doing it from your local network and communicating over the Internet for each registration, then it probably will take days because of general network latency. If you can't let your program run for days (although I don't see why you couldn't let it do just that), then you might be better off executing your code from within the Azure datacenter, on your own worker role, for example.